# Copy chosen Wikipedia articles into own wiki?

Tags: php, mysql, mediawiki, wikipedia

is there a way to batch copy certain wikipedia articles(about 10,000) to my own mediawiki site?

EDIT:
How do I do this without overwriting similarly named articles/pages?
Also I don't plan on using illegal means (crawlers etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to obtain a specific set of articles, then you may be able to use the Export page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export) to obtain an XML dump of the pages involved; you can export multiple pages at once, although you may wish to space out your requests.

You can import the XML dumps into MediaWiki using `Special:Import` or one of the import scripts in `maintenance/`.

Comment: Does this include images? If not is there an automatic method to obtain images as well?

Comment: It doesn't include images because it's a straight XML dump of the page information, revision metadata and text, and the format hasn't been expanded to include the binary image data. Strictly speaking, it's a technical limitation. In theory, you could import copyright-infringing text and the software wouldn't stop that.

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia database is available for [download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_database)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wikihow.com/Import-XML-Dumps-to-Your-MediaWiki-Wiki

This helps you, I wish.

Comment: On SO, when providing a link to an external site, it is often best to give at least a high level summary of what the contents are in case the external link changes or is deleted. Future SO visitors will still have *something* to work with.